# set javascaript variable in the php (php is in javascript)

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

i am write php code in side JavaScript.

**this type:-**

```
function load(){
                var lan= "22.3000";
                var lng= "70.7833";
                var radius = "7000";
                var xml;
                var data = lan+","+lng+","+radius;
        xml = '<?php          echo file_get_contents("http://services.gisgraphy.com/geoloc/search?lat=23.00&lng=72.00&radius10000");?>'
                xmlDoc = $.parseXML( xml );
        $xml = $( xmlDoc );
           abc= xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("asciiName")[0].firstChild.nodeValue;
        alert(abc);
            }
```

i want to set in php JavaScript variable value lan lng and radius when page load

Comment: PHP gets evaluated _before_ JavaScript. I think you might be missing some basic concepts...

Comment: i don't know but what wrong i do??

Comment: i am write this code in .php file

Answer (score 2):

what you want to do is to load your page then do an ajax call to load the page with the `lat` and `lng` and `radius` parameters.

Comment: i am also try this but its take time to load...

Comment: create one php file and post the JavaScript variable throw ajax